# DevForce supporting Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, breeze, devforce, breeze-sharp

I came across this post on Ideablade´s forum: http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=4635&KW=xamarin&PID=17331&title=devforce-2014#17331

I find this question interesting, but there is no response from Ideablade.

Does Ideablade have any plans for DevForce supporting PCL or Xamarin in the future?

Or can DevForce already be used with Xamarin? Any samples?

Comment: SO is not the appropriate forum to ask about DevForce's future plans.  Ask the company directly.

Comment: The company asked us (customers) to use stakoverflow from now on. They closed their own forum where, before, we were able to ask such question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently no plans to support Xamarin in DevForce.  IdeaBlade's new product, Breeze#, can be used with Xamarin.  See http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-sharp for more info.

Comment: Thank you. What is the main difference between DevForce and Breeze#?

Comment: Breeze# is a single PCL providing a subset of DevForce capabilities.  There's a full comparison at http://www.breezejs.com/blog/breezesharp-or-devforce.